# Are these two variables indepedent?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Below is an exercise that I did. However, I have concerns I did it wrong. In particular, I am concerned that I calculated $f_1(x)$ or $f_2(x)$ incorrectly.

Problem:
Let $X$ and  $Y$ have joint density function
the density function
$$ f(x,y)  = \begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{y} & 0 < x < y, 0 < y < 1 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
Determine if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?
Answer:

$X$ and $Y$ iff
$$ f(x,y) = f_1(x)f_2(y) $$
where
$$ f_1(x) = \int f(x,y) \,\, dy $$
and
$$ f_2(y) = \int f(x,y)  \,\, dx $$
In this case, we have:
\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &= \int \dfrac{1}{y} \,\, dy \\
f_1(x) &= \dfrac{x}{y} \\
f_2(y) &= \int \dfrac{1}{y} \,\, dy \\
f_2(y) &= - \dfrac{y^{-2}}{2} \\
f_1(x) f_2(x) &= \left( \dfrac{x}{y} \right) \left( \dfrac{y^{-2}}{2} \right) \\
f_1(x) f_2(x) &= \dfrac{ x }{ 2y^3} \\
f(x,y) &\neq f_1(x) f_2(x) \\
\end{align*}
Hence we conclude the variables are not independent.

Answer (score 3):

To see that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, it is much easier to choose a particular case.  $$\Pr[X > 1/2 \mid Y < 1/2] = 0,$$ but $$\Pr[X > 1/2] > 0.$$

---

That said, your solution is not correct because your marginal densities need to consider the joint support of $X$ and $Y$.  You also have a few computational errors.  Specifically,

$$f_1(x) = \int_{y=0}^1 f(x,y) \, dy = \int_{y=\color{red}{x}}^1 \frac{1}{y} \, dy,$$ because as the joint density clearly states, $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x \ge y$.  Hence,
$$f_1(x) = \log 1 - \log x = -\log x, \quad 0 < x < 1.$$

The marginal density of $Y$ is
$$f_2(y) = \int_{x=0}^1 f(x,y) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^{\color{red}{y}} \frac{1}{y} \, d\color{red}{x} = 1, \quad 0 < y < 1.$$
So the marginal density of $Y$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.  But it is obvious that
$$f (x,y) \ne f_1(x) f_2(y).$$  But as I showed above, it is unnecessary to resort to the explicit calculation of the marginal densities to conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, since
$\Pr[A \mid B] \ne \Pr[A]$ for the particular events $A : X > 1/2$ and $B : Y < 1/2]$.

Comment: Your argument doesn’t work since you are conditioning on a null set

Comment: @Andrew Change it trivially, and now you cannot object.